# Mysql_query how to use it with a "dynamic" database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

Today i'm working on my website, trying to display the last winner of the game. Here's my code :

```
 $lastgame = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");

$winnercost = fetchinfo("cost","games","id",$lastgame-1);
$winnerpercent = round(fetchinfo("percent","games","id",$lastgame-1),1);
$winneravatar = fetchinfo("avatar","users","steamid",$lastwinner);
$winnername = fetchinfo("name","users","steamid",$lastwinner);



echo '<p>Game #'.$lastgame.'</p>'; 
echo '<p>'.$winnername.' won the jackpot</p>'; 
echo '<p> valued at '.$winnercost.'</p>'; 
echo '<p>with a winning chance of '.$winnerpercent.'</p>';
```

The point is i use fetchinfo only, so it displays informations but not in real time, i have to refresh my page to display the latest winner. I'll need to make a mysql_query i guess.

My problem is that i don't understand how to use the mysql_query, knowing that each time a winner wins it creates a new row in my table. For example :

```
id : 1
startime :1441330544
total price : 3.17
Winner : Foxy
steam id : 76561198042016725
Percent chances to win : 98.7381703
Number of total item : 2
module : 0.24973750
```

Anyone has a solution to help me ? this -1

```
,$lastgame-1),1);
```

gives me some difficulties :(

The result on the website atm :

Game #4
Foxy won the jackpot
valued at 3.31
with a winning chance of 94.6

Comment: Use from here [PHPLink](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Since no-one else has mentioned it, let me point out that PHP's `mysql_query()` function is deprecated (along with the whole `mysql` API), and will be removed entirely in the next version of PHP. You should switch your code to use the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead. Also if you're a PHP beginner and you're using the `mysql_xxx()` functions at all, then it probably means that you've been using some very old tutorials to teach yourself PHP; I strongly recommend trying to find some more up-to-date tutorials, because PHP as a language has moved on a lot since the `mysql` funcs were deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I think the simplest query you could use would be something like:

```
select * from <tblname> order by steamid desc limit 1;
```

For the auto refresh you could do one of two things:

```
1) you could add: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> in the header of your html and the page will automatically refresh every 5 seconds.  (basic)

2) you could use ajax to make a call to execute the query and update the page which is a much nicer user experience (more advanced)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an api page with a php or any other preferred serverside programming web language that when called gives you the most up to date query results it can.

Then create a loop in javascript that every x amount of seconds sends an ajax request to the api page and using that data,you can dynamically update your fields with jquery or js (really doesnt matter - you probably know how to update/change text)

Here some resources:

**ajax getting started**
[link 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

**more ajax**
[link 2](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)